# Why doesn't document.write work on a variable with HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, document.write

`document.write` on a variable works fine. `document.write` on a string with HTML tags also works fine. However, when trying to use `document.write` on a JS variable with HTML tags, the program doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
var Foo = "Foo Variable"
document.write(Foo)
document.write("<h1>Foo</h1>");
document.write(<h1>Foo</h1>)
```

The first three lines work fine, but the last line doesn't display anything. I believe this is a syntax error, but no matter what I try it still doesn't seem to work. I've tried putting just the HTML tags in quotes with no avail. Is there any way for me to have a string variable expressed as a header? In other words, I want the page to display the words "Foo Variable" as an h1 header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Edited it, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a syntax error. If you want to output the contents of the `Foo` variable within `h1` tags, you need to use a template literal (ES2015+) or string concatenation:

```
// Template literal (ES2015+)
var Foo = "Foo Variable";
document.write(`<h1>${Foo}</h1>`);
```

or

```
// String concatenation
var Foo = "Foo Variable";
document.write("<h1>" + Foo + "</h1>");
```

**But**, there's almost no place for `document.write` in modern web programming. Instead, use [the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to add or update elements.

Comment: Thank you, I will mark as correct when allowed. A follow up question - just out of curiosity, can you have a tag as a variable? For example can you set ```var Foo = "<br  />"```? Would that display as a line break when called? (It seems like kind of an unnecessary question, but just out of curiosity.)

Comment: @FruDe - What matters is the string you pass to `document.write` (or `insertAdjacentHTML`, etc.). So sure, if that string is from a variable and it contains a tag, that'll work. (Side note: You don't "call" variables. You call *functions*. You *use* variables.)